# Room with Subclass

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm looking to persist some data classes.  I've been investigating using Room for this, which is very straight forward to do if it's just a case of a stand alone data class.  However the objects I am trying to persist are sub classes, which adds a layer of complexity.

**THIS CODE HAS NOT BEEN COMPILED, WRITTEN IN SO FOR ILLUSTRATION PURPOSES ONLY**

So with a simple straight forward class

```
    @Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
   public class Event implements MyEvent {
   public static final String TABLE_NAME = "events";
   public static final String DATE_FIELD = "date";

   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
   private int id;
   private String name;
   private String description;
   @ColumnInfo(name = DATE_FIELD)
   private LocalDateTime date;

   public Event(int id, String name, String description, LocalDateTime date) {
       this.id = id;
       this.name = name;
       this.description = description;
       this.date = date;
   }

   @Override
   public int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   @Override
   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }

   @Override
   public LocalDateTime getDate() {
       return date;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return "Event{" +
               "id=" + id +
               ", name='" + name + '\'' +
               ", description='" + description + '\'' +
               ", date=" + date +
               '}';
   }

   public long getDaysUntil() {
       return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(LocalDateTime.now(), getDate());
   }
}
```

That's straight forward but if you have for example

```
  public class MusicEvent extends Event implements MyEvents {

  private String musicType;
  private boolean supportActs;

   @Override
   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   @Override
   public String getDescription() {
       return description;
   }

   @Override
   public LocalDateTime getDate() {
       return date;
   }

  public void setMusicType(String musicType) {
      this.musicType = musicType;
  }

  public String getMusicType() {
      return this.musicType;
  }

  public void setSupportActs(boolean supportActs) {
      this.supportActs = supportActs;
  }

    public boolean getSupportActs() {
      return this.supportActs;
  }
  }

  public interface MyEvents {
     int getId();
     String getName();
     String getDescription();
     LocalDate getDate();
  }
```

So what I want to do is have one table of events, I don't want to have multiple tables for e.g. music events, film events, drama events.

Or if they all implement MyEvents they can all be type MyEvents.

I would like to be able to persist all Event objects and when required retrieve all event objects.

If anyone could share some info on this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: "I don't want to have multiple tables for e.g. music events, film events, drama events" -- inheritance is difficult to model in any ORM. AFAIK, Room does not handle inheritance (i.e., having some column that indicates what class to use for creating an entity from the row), nor does it handle the concept of an entity table containing all possible columns from all subclasses. It is possible that another Android ORM can handle these things. More likely, you will need to relax your requirement or switch to something that is more of an object database (e.g., Realm), which may model this better.

Comment: @CommonsWare Many thanks for coming back to me, from my research and experimenting I feared as much.  It looks like I may formulate a different approach!

Comment: JDXA ORM for Android can handle class inheritance well. You may save Event and MyEvent objects in separate tables or in the same table. By default, a query on a superclass also retrieves the qualifying objects of the subclasses (polymorphism). However, you may restrict the selection to only the superclass objects. Disclaimer: I am the architect of JDXA ORM.

Comment: Any further info on this? I am in similiar situation and still thinking if there is possibility to have one DAO for similiar objects, and e.g one insert method for all object of subclass